# Prime number loop only writes "2" to console. Java

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, numbers, primes

I am more or less completely new to Java. I thought I would try to write a simple loop to output a list of prime numbers under 100 into the console, as practice - however as you can probably tell by the title of this question all it gives is 2 and that's it. I am using Eclipse to edit and run my code. Here it is:

```
    public class PrimeGen {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            for (int num = 1,     // number to test
                     testfac = 1, // start factor to divide into num
                     numfacs = 0; // number of factors in current iteration of num
                 num <= 100;
                 num++)
            {
                while (testfac <= num){
                    if (num/testfac == Math.round(num/testfac)) numfacs++; // add 1 to numfacs if it divides evenly
                    testfac++;
                }
                if (numfacs == 2) System.out.println(num);
                numfacs = 0;
                testfac = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

I would be extremely grateful if someone could help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: there are millions of questions related to this please search!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `if (num/testfac == Math.round(num/testfac))` with `if (num % testfac == 0)`.

The problem is `Math.round(num/testfac)` will always equal `num/testfac` because you are doing integer division. Use % to check for divisibility.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much @nitegazer2003! :D  I'll remember that in future.

Answer (score 0):

Test for divisibility like

```
if (num % testfac == 0)
```

And since, every number is divisible by 1 and itself you can save your loop cycles by not checking divisibility on them. Start with `testfac = 2`; loop `while (testfac < num)` and check `if (numfacs > 0)`.

Comment: Thank you too. I was trying to get the programme to just work first and made it as simple as possible. I do know that every integer divides by 1 but the optimisation would have come later!

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Just giving some pointers. (No offence meant :)

Comment: None taken ;) Would an optimisation like that make an appreciable change of speed in a working programme?

Comment: For the given prime number programme; no, not much. It's subjective to what's being done in the loop and how costly that operation is. But, in Algorithm Analysis you usually compute complexity of a solution with the Big O(n) notation based on the number of steps required for an n-sized input. And, there a significant effort is made to keep the algorithm as slim as possible.

Comment: Loads more research for me to do then ;)  Thanks again.

Comment: Don't worry, you'll get there.

Comment: @SketchRusty Check out the "Sieve of Eratosthenes" algorithm, which is one of the fastest algorithms for generating primes up to some number.

Comment: Thank you so so much for that info, I have another practice project now :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit more optimized method is the method2.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int N = 100000;
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int[] v1 = method1(N);
    long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int[] v2 = method2(N);
    long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println( "m1:"+(t2-t1)+"  m2:"+(t3-t2) );

    int m1=0,m2=0;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) if(v1[i]==1) m1++;
    System.out.println();
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) if(v2[i]==0) m2++;
    assert m1 == m2;
    System.out.println(m1+" == "+m2);

}

public static int[] method1(int N)
{
    int[] vector = new int[N];

    for (int num = 1,     // number to test
            testfac = 1, // start factor to divide into num
            numfacs = 0; // number of factors in current iteration of num
            num <= N;
            num++)
    {
        while (testfac <= num){
            if (num % testfac == 0 ) numfacs++; // add 1 to numfacs if it divides evenly
            testfac++;
        }
        if (numfacs == 2) vector[num]=1;
        numfacs = 0;
        testfac = 1;
    }
    return vector;
}

public static int[] method2(int N)
{
    int[] vector = new int[N];
    vector[0]=1;
    vector[1]=1;

    for(int n=2; n<N/2; n++ )
    {
        if(vector[n]==1)
            continue;
        int m=n;
        for(int i=2; ;i++)
        {
            m = i*n;
            if(m>=N)
                break;
            vector[m]=1;
        }
    }
    return vector;
}
```